# docker swarm deploy ERROR: "Pool overlaps with other one on this address space" :: portainer on swarm via traefik reverse proxy

Tags: docker, networking, traefik, swarm, portainer

#### Unfortunately, I cannot figure out:

1. **"which pool"** overlaps
2. with **which "other one"**
3. On "which address space"
4. ...and: **"what exactly is overlapping here"**
   ... so, I do have some problems with performing the right measures and modifications...

**Context:** docker swarm, running on three nodes (one master, two workers, locally distributed VPS Ubuntu machines with docker & docker-compose installed. )
→ portainer shall now be added, but hangs with this error (I did already remove everything at least I think so - I left the swarm itself as it was) and did set it up new (and did try out other images.

- traefik_proxy & its dashboard are running - with a nice functioning letsencrypt tls / certbot integration (on the master-node)

---

```
root@kube-master:~# docker stack ps portainer
```

1. root@kube-master:~# **docker stack ps portainer** (1.st part with the portainer-agent) is alternating between RUNNING and SHUTDOWN

```
ID             NAME                                            IMAGE                          NODE           DESIRED STATE   CURRENT STATE           ERROR                              PORTS
q6c7jxswns8a   portainer_agent.cr7onfse17oeikdwaj4xbqfkk       portainer/agent:2.9.1          kube-worker2   Running         Running 17 hours ago                                       
fz1bnhcecpom    \_ portainer_agent.cr7onfse17oeikdwaj4xbqfkk   portainer/agent:2.9.1          kube-worker2   Shutdown        Shutdown 17 hours ago                                      
xu8pmcrg9ne4   portainer_agent.t270o40e5h6s2ah60smwt41x4       portainer/agent:2.9.1          kube-master    Running         Running 17 hours ago                                       
x2j7qpefwhtx    \_ portainer_agent.t270o40e5h6s2ah60smwt41x4   portainer/agent:2.9.1          kube-master    Shutdown        Shutdown 17 hours ago                                      
akgfyap2ft7w   portainer_agent.xj7crqbw6873mqteecdergqee       portainer/agent:2.9.1          kube-worker1   Running         Running 17 hours ago                                       
v2ik2btma450    \_ portainer_agent.xj7crqbw6873mqteecdergqee   portainer/agent:2.9.1          kube-worker1   Shutdown        Shutdown 17 hours ago
```

---

```
2nd part of the root@kube-master:~# **docker stack ps portainer** then shows the "pool overlap error"


ijuafoa5336g   portainer_portainer.1                           portainer/portainer-ce:2.9.1   kube-master    Shutdown        Rejected 4 seconds ago    "Pool overlaps with other one …"   
3q6rrhj4rq5g    \_ portainer_portainer.1                       portainer/portainer-ce:2.9.1   kube-master    Shutdown        Rejected 10 seconds ago   "Pool overlaps with other one …"   
n5jvex2iq5jz    \_ portainer_portainer.1                       portainer/portainer-ce:2.9.1   kube-master    Shutdown        Rejected 13 seconds ago   "Pool overlaps with other one …"   
lwydktonmxvo    \_ portainer_portainer.1                       portainer/portainer-ce:2.9.1   kube-master    Shutdown        Rejected 16 seconds ago   "Pool overlaps with other one …"
```

---

#### ERROR: "Pool overlaps with other one on this address space"

---

```
root@masterNode:~/swarmportainer# docker inspect ijuafoa5336g

[
    {
        "ID": "ijuafoa5336gk6rlvsvdjdohf",
        "Version": {
            "Index": 418878
        },
        "CreatedAt": "2021-10-15T14:22:59.352628943Z",
        "UpdatedAt": "2021-10-15T14:23:04.559430221Z",
        "Labels": {},
        "Spec": {
            "ContainerSpec": {
                "Image": "portainer/portainer-ce:2.9.1@sha256:76ff22486bcd3713631b5f317efcb69e707a122fe96ffcc0589cf2d3e8e6b890",
                "Labels": {
                    "com.docker.stack.namespace": "portainer"
                },
                "Args": [
                    "-H",
                    "tcp://tasks.agent:9001",
                    "--tlsskipverify"
                ],
                "Privileges": {
                    "CredentialSpec": null,
                    "SELinuxContext": null
                },
                "Mounts": [
                    {
                        "Type": "volume",
                        "Source": "portainer_portainer_data",
                        "Target": "/data",
                        "VolumeOptions": {
                            "Labels": {
                                "com.docker.stack.namespace": "portainer"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "Isolation": "default"
            },
            "Resources": {},
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Condition": "on-failure",
                "Delay": 5000000000,
                "MaxAttempts": 3
            },
            "Placement": {
                "Constraints": [
                    "node.role == manager"
                ],
                "Platforms": [
                    {
                        "Architecture": "amd64",
                        "OS": "linux"
                    },
                    {
                        "OS": "linux"
                    },
                    {
                        "Architecture": "arm64",
                        "OS": "linux"
                    },
                    {
                        "Architecture": "ppc64le",
                        "OS": "linux"
                    },
                    {
                        "Architecture": "s390x",
                        "OS": "linux"
                    },
                    {
                        "Architecture": "amd64",
                        "OS": "windows"
                    },
                    {
                        "Architecture": "amd64",
                        "OS": "windows"
                    },
                    {
                        "Architecture": "amd64",
                        "OS": "windows"
                    },
                    {
                        "Architecture": "amd64",
                        "OS": "windows"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Networks": [
                {
                    "Target": "suyp5ojm8z36pjhfmg2ezgznn",
                    "Aliases": [
                        "portainer"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Target": "9tk88azb36vfqfkil7h0khacf",
                    "Aliases": [
                        "portainer"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "ForceUpdate": 0
        },
        "ServiceID": "5lic71rrdduxamm3lzguds0qk",
        "Slot": 1,
        "NodeID": "t270o40e5h6s2ah60smwt41x4",
        "Status": {
            "Timestamp": "2021-10-15T14:23:00.561467279Z",
            "State": "rejected",
            "Message": "preparing",
            "Err": "Pool overlaps with other one on this address space",
            "ContainerStatus": {
                "ContainerID": "",
                "PID": 0,
                "ExitCode": 0
            },
            "PortStatus": {}
        },
        "DesiredState": "shutdown",
        "NetworksAttachments": [
            {
                "Network": {
                    "ID": "926lp9ngcgvnew4b6zxjvzwvn",
                    "Version": {
                        "Index": 416802
                    },
                    "CreatedAt": "2021-10-10T19:03:53.880298398Z",
                    "UpdatedAt": "2021-10-15T00:48:58.348694345Z",
                    "Spec": {
                        "Name": "ingress",
                        "Labels": {},
                        "DriverConfiguration": {
                            "Name": "overlay",
                            "Options": {
                                "encrypted": ""
                            }
                        },
                        "Ingress": true,
                        "IPAMOptions": {
                            "Driver": {
                                "Name": "default"
                            },
                            "Configs": [
                                {
                                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.1/16",
                                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "Scope": "swarm"
                    },
                    "DriverState": {
                        "Name": "overlay",
                        "Options": {
                            "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "4100",
                            "encrypted": ""
                        }
                    },
                    "IPAMOptions": {
                        "Driver": {
                            "Name": "default"
                        },
                        "Configs": [
                            {
                                "Subnet": "172.17.0.1/16",
                                "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "Addresses": [
                    "172.17.1.66/16"
                ]
            },
            {
                "Network": {
                    "ID": "suyp5ojm8z36pjhfmg2ezgznn",
                    "Version": {
                        "Index": 418713
                    },
                    "CreatedAt": "2021-10-15T03:06:27.264974088Z",
                    "UpdatedAt": "2021-10-15T03:06:27.27167032Z",
                    "Spec": {
                        "Name": "portainer_cloud-proxy",
                        "Labels": {
                            "com.docker.stack.namespace": "portainer"
                        },
                        "DriverConfiguration": {
                            "Name": "overlay"
                        },
                        "Attachable": true,
                        "Scope": "swarm"
                    },
                    "DriverState": {
                        "Name": "overlay",
                        "Options": {
                            "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "4103"
                        }
                    },
                    "IPAMOptions": {
                        "Driver": {
                            "Name": "default"
                        },
                        "Configs": [
                            {
                                "Subnet": "10.0.6.0/24",
                                "Gateway": "10.0.6.1"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "Addresses": [
                    "10.0.6.20/24"
                ]
            },
            {
                "Network": {
                    "ID": "9tk88azb36vfqfkil7h0khacf",
                    "Version": {
                        "Index": 418837
                    },
                    "CreatedAt": "2021-10-15T12:57:32.860888933Z",
                    "UpdatedAt": "2021-10-15T12:57:32.862926323Z",
                    "Spec": {
                        "Name": "portainer_portainer_agent_network",
                        "Labels": {
                            "com.docker.stack.namespace": "portainer"
                        },
                        "DriverConfiguration": {
                            "Name": "overlay"
                        },
                        "Attachable": true,
                        "Scope": "swarm"
                    },
                    "DriverState": {
                        "Name": "overlay",
                        "Options": {
                            "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "4107"
                        }
                    },
                    "IPAMOptions": {
                        "Driver": {
                            "Name": "default"
                        },
                        "Configs": [
                            {
                                "Subnet": "10.0.10.0/24",
                                "Gateway": "10.0.10.1"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "Addresses": [
                    "10.0.10.9/24"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

##### checking(=inspecting) the ServiceID with the error:

```
root@kube-master:~/swarmportainer# docker inspect 5lic71rrdduxamm3lzguds0qk

[
    {
        "ID": "5lic71rrdduxamm3lzguds0qk",
        "Version": {
            "Index": 418849
        },
        "CreatedAt": "2021-10-15T02:41:06.984914145Z",
        "UpdatedAt": "2021-10-15T14:22:49.339347775Z",
        "Spec": {
            "Name": "portainer_portainer",
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.stack.image": "portainer/portainer-ce:2.9.1",
                "com.docker.stack.namespace": "portainer",
                "traefik.enable": "true\"",
                "traefik.http.routers.portainer.entrypoints": "websecure",
                "traefik.http.routers.portainer.rule": "Host(`portainer.domain.com`)",
                "traefik.http.routers.portainer.service": "portainer_svc",
                "traefik.http.routers.portainer.tls.certresolver": "letsencrypt",
                "traefik.http.services.portainer_svc.loadbalancer.server.port": "9000"
            },
            "TaskTemplate": {
                "ContainerSpec": {
                    "Image": "portainer/portainer-ce:2.9.1@sha256:76ff22486bcd3713631b5f317efcb69e707a122fe96ffcc0589cf2d3e8e6b890",
                    "Labels": {
                        "com.docker.stack.namespace": "portainer"
                    },
                    "Args": [
                        "-H",
                        "tcp://tasks.agent:9001",
                        "--tlsskipverify"
                    ],
                    "Privileges": {
                        "CredentialSpec": null,
                        "SELinuxContext": null
                    },
                    "Mounts": [
                        {
                            "Type": "volume",
                            "Source": "portainer_portainer_data",
                            "Target": "/data",
                            "VolumeOptions": {
                                "Labels": {
                                    "com.docker.stack.namespace": "portainer"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "StopGracePeriod": 10000000000,
                    "DNSConfig": {},
                    "Isolation": "default"
                },
                "Resources": {},
                "RestartPolicy": {
                    "Condition": "on-failure",
                    "Delay": 5000000000,
                    "MaxAttempts": 3
                },
                "Placement": {
                    "Constraints": [
                        "node.role == manager"
                    ],
                    "Platforms": [
                        {
                            "Architecture": "amd64",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "arm64",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "ppc64le",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "s390x",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "amd64",
                            "OS": "windows"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "amd64",
                            "OS": "windows"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "amd64",
                            "OS": "windows"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "amd64",
                            "OS": "windows"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Networks": [
                    {
                        "Target": "suyp5ojm8z36pjhfmg2ezgznn",
                        "Aliases": [
                            "portainer"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "Target": "9tk88azb36vfqfkil7h0khacf",
                        "Aliases": [
                            "portainer"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "ForceUpdate": 0,
                "Runtime": "container"
            },
            "Mode": {
                "Replicated": {
                    "Replicas": 1
                }
            },
            "UpdateConfig": {
                "Parallelism": 1,
                "FailureAction": "pause",
                "Monitor": 5000000000,
                "MaxFailureRatio": 0,
                "Order": "stop-first"
            },
            "RollbackConfig": {
                "Parallelism": 1,
                "FailureAction": "pause",
                "Monitor": 5000000000,
                "MaxFailureRatio": 0,
                "Order": "stop-first"
            },
            "EndpointSpec": {
                "Mode": "vip",
                "Ports": [
                    {
                        "Protocol": "tcp",
                        "TargetPort": 8000,
                        "PublishedPort": 8000,
                        "PublishMode": "ingress"
                    },
                    {
                        "Protocol": "tcp",
                        "TargetPort": 9000,
                        "PublishedPort": 9000,
                        "PublishMode": "ingress"
                    },
                    {
                        "Protocol": "tcp",
                        "TargetPort": 9443,
                        "PublishedPort": 9443,
                        "PublishMode": "ingress"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "PreviousSpec": {
            "Name": "portainer_portainer",
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.stack.image": "portainer/portainer-ce:2.9.1",
                "com.docker.stack.namespace": "portainer",
                "traefik.enable": "true\"",
                "traefik.http.routers.portainer.entrypoints": "websecure",
                "traefik.http.routers.portainer.rule": "Host(`portainer.domain.com`)",
                "traefik.http.routers.portainer.tls.certresolver": "letsencrypt",
                "traefik.http.services.portainer.loadbalancer.server.port": "9000"
            },
            "TaskTemplate": {
                "ContainerSpec": {
                    "Image": "portainer/portainer-ce:2.9.1@sha256:76ff22486bcd3713631b5f317efcb69e707a122fe96ffcc0589cf2d3e8e6b890",
                    "Labels": {
                        "com.docker.stack.namespace": "portainer"
                    },
                    "Args": [
                        "-H",
                        "tcp://tasks.agent:9001",
                        "--tlsskipverify"
                    ],
                    "Privileges": {
                        "CredentialSpec": null,
                        "SELinuxContext": null
                    },
                    "Mounts": [
                        {
                            "Type": "volume",
                            "Source": "portainer_portainer_data",
                            "Target": "/data",
                            "VolumeOptions": {
                                "Labels": {
                                    "com.docker.stack.namespace": "portainer"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "Isolation": "default"
                },
                "Resources": {},
                "RestartPolicy": {
                    "Condition": "on-failure",
                    "Delay": 5000000000,
                    "MaxAttempts": 3
                },
                "Placement": {
                    "Constraints": [
                        "node.role == manager",
                        "node.labels.cloud-public.traefik-certificates == true"
                    ],
                    "Platforms": [
                        {
                            "Architecture": "amd64",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "arm64",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "ppc64le",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "s390x",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "amd64",
                            "OS": "windows"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "amd64",
                            "OS": "windows"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "amd64",
                            "OS": "windows"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "amd64",
                            "OS": "windows"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Networks": [
                    {
                        "Target": "mtusklowmyx7z2cd75pobuyub",
                        "Aliases": [
                            "portainer"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "ForceUpdate": 0,
                "Runtime": "container"
            },
            "Mode": {
                "Replicated": {
                    "Replicas": 1
                }
            },
            "EndpointSpec": {
                "Mode": "vip",
                "Ports": [
                    {
                        "Protocol": "tcp",
                        "TargetPort": 8000,
                        "PublishedPort": 8000,
                        "PublishMode": "ingress"
                    },
                    {
                        "Protocol": "tcp",
                        "TargetPort": 9000,
                        "PublishedPort": 9000,
                        "PublishMode": "ingress"
                    },
                    {
                        "Protocol": "tcp",
                        "TargetPort": 9443,
                        "PublishedPort": 9443,
                        "PublishMode": "ingress"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "Endpoint": {
            "Spec": {
                "Mode": "vip",
                "Ports": [
                    {
                        "Protocol": "tcp",
                        "TargetPort": 8000,
                        "PublishedPort": 8000,
                        "PublishMode": "ingress"
                    },
                    {
                        "Protocol": "tcp",
                        "TargetPort": 9000,
                        "PublishedPort": 9000,
                        "PublishMode": "ingress"
                    },
                    {
                        "Protocol": "tcp",
                        "TargetPort": 9443,
                        "PublishedPort": 9443,
                        "PublishMode": "ingress"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Ports": [
                {
                    "Protocol": "tcp",
                    "TargetPort": 8000,
                    "PublishedPort": 8000,
                    "PublishMode": "ingress"
                },
                {
                    "Protocol": "tcp",
                    "TargetPort": 9000,
                    "PublishedPort": 9000,
                    "PublishMode": "ingress"
                },
                {
                    "Protocol": "tcp",
                    "TargetPort": 9443,
                    "PublishedPort": 9443,
                    "PublishMode": "ingress"
                }
            ],
            "VirtualIPs": [
                {
                    "NetworkID": "926lp9ngcgvnew4b6zxjvzwvn",
                    "Addr": "172.17.0.5/16"
                },
                {
                    "NetworkID": "suyp5ojm8z36pjhfmg2ezgznn",
                    "Addr": "10.0.6.16/24"
                },
                {
                    "NetworkID": "9tk88azb36vfqfkil7h0khacf",
                    "Addr": "10.0.10.2/24"
                }
            ]
        },
        "UpdateStatus": {
            "State": "paused",
            "StartedAt": "2021-10-15T14:22:49.079195959Z",
            "Message": "update paused due to failure or early termination of task lwydktonmxvolxqs0h4oi2yzb"
        }
    }
]
```

... I am not sure, if I am spotting it from the right perspective - just drop me a line, I'd really appreciate receiving some help & ideas here

Comment: I, the questioner, do not need the answer anymore. I got it up and running by rebuilding the container and attaching it to the swarm and network. if sb has the answer: feel free to answer, I did some search (of course) before posting and could not find an answer to this error within the www...

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer for how to solve this error, **but "my solution" the way I/ others can get the portainer in traefik on swarm running:**

deploy to your existing your-traefik-stack via:

```
docker stack deploy -c portainer_traefik-proxy.yml your-traefik-stack
```

hint: docker stack ls → check your available Swarm stacks

below: portainer_traefik-proxy.yml file:

```
version: "3.8"

services:


  agent:
    image: portainer/agent

    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /var/lib/docker/volumes:/var/lib/docker/volumes
    networks:
      - cloud-edge
    deploy:
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager

  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer-ce:latest
    command: -H tcp://tasks.agent:9001 --tlsskipverify
    volumes:
      - portainer_data:/data
    networks:
      - cloud-edge
      - cloud-public

    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
      labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.middlewares.portainer-redirect-websecure.redirectscheme.scheme=https

      - traefik.http.routers.portainer-web.middlewares=portainer-redirect-websecure
      - traefik.http.routers.portainer-web.rule=Host(`subdomain.domain.xyz`) # <-- set your subdomain.domain.toplevel
      - traefik.http.routers.portainer-web.entrypoints=web
      - traefik.http.routers.portainer-websecure.rule=Host(`subdomain.domain.xyz`) # <-- set your subdomain.domain.toplevel
 
      - traefik.http.routers.whoami.tls=true             
      - traefik.http.routers.portainer-web.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt
      - traefik.http.routers.portainer-web.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.portainer-web.entrypoints=websecure
      - traefik.http.services.portainer-websecure.loadbalancer.server.port=9000


networks:
  cloud-public:
    external: true
  cloud-edge:
    external: true

volumes:
   portainer_data:
```

###### some notes:

1. ensure naming of YOUR traefik setup! (sometimes not "web" but "HTTP" and other name for resolver or different encryption ...)
2. must have created these overlay networks before / with swarm-scope, like:

```
docker network create --subnet 10.11.0.0/16 --driver overlay \
  --scope swarm --opt encrypted --attachable cloud-edge    


 docker network create --subnet 10.12.0.0/16 --driver overlay \
  --scope swarm --opt encrypted --attachable cloud-public
```

3. perhaps, the volumes should be set towards your NFS-prepared directories
   ...